# Iteration on sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, cauchy-sequences, fixed-point-theorems

I am trying to find a general formula for this sequence, in order to find its limit (has to be this way):

$$X_{k+1} = \frac {X_k} 2 + \frac 1 {X_k}$$

I cannot get a grasp on it; after $2$ or $3$ iterations, the sequence gets huge and I don't see the pattern.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint : This is the Heron-method for calculating $\sqrt{2}$. It converges for every positive start value, try it with $X_0=1$ , for example.

Comment: Has none, the main point is getting the general formula and work with that in the following questions.

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to find the general term ? I think, you only have to show that the limit is $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Yes I am, they asked to fix and Xo and recursively define the sequence.

Comment: What do you mean by "the sequence is huge" ?

Comment: I mean it grows without any obvious pattern, so keeps getting bigger after each iteration.

Comment: @Santiago: we mustn't live on the same planet. That sequence corresponds to the well-known method of Heron for the square roots, and it converges monotonously from any intial value to $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_0=\sqrt 2$, then the sequence is constant, so we can assume $X_0\not = \sqrt 2$. We may also assume that $X_0>0$, as the negative case is the same.

Let $X_0=\sqrt 2\cdot\frac {r+1}{r-1} $, or $r=\frac{X_0+\sqrt2}{X_0-\sqrt2}$, then the closed form is $X_k=\sqrt 2\cdot\frac {r^{2^k}+1}{r^{2^k}-1}$. The way to get the closed form is as follows.

Dividing by $\sqrt 2$:
$$\frac {X_{k+1}}{\sqrt 2}=\frac 12(\frac {X_{k}}{\sqrt 2}+\frac {\sqrt 2}{X_{k}})$$

Substituting $\frac {X_{k}}{\sqrt 2}=S_k+1$:
$$S_{k+1}+1=\frac 12 \cdot(S_k+1+\frac 1{S_k+1})$$
$$S_{k+1}=\frac 12 \cdot(S_k-1+\frac 1{S_k+1})$$
$$S_{k+1}=\frac 12 \cdot\frac {S_k^2}{S_k+1}$$
Taking the inverse:
$$\frac 1{S_{k+1}}=2  \cdot\frac {S_{k}+1}{S_k^2}$$
$$\frac 1{S_{k+1}}= 2\cdot (\frac 1{S_{k}})^2+2\cdot \frac 1{S_{k}}$$
Completing the square:
$$\frac 1{S_{k+1}}+\frac 12=2\cdot(\frac 1{S_{k}}+\frac 12)^2$$
$$\frac 2{S_{k+1}}+1=(\frac 2{S_{k}}+1)^2$$
This means each term is the square of the previous term, which we can denote as  $\frac 2{S_{k}}+1=r^{2^{k}}$. Substituting everything back into $X_k$ then we have the close form.

Proving that the closed form is actually correct:
\begin{align}
\frac {X_k}2+\frac 1{X_k}
&=\frac 1{\sqrt2} \cdot (\frac {r^{2^k}+1}{r^{2^k}-1}+\frac {r^{2^k}-1}{r^{2^k}+1})\\
&=\frac 1{\sqrt2} \cdot  \frac {(r^{2^k}+1)^2+({r^{2^k}-1})^2}{(r^{2^k}-1)({r^{2^k}+1})} \\
&=\frac 1{\sqrt2}\cdot  \frac {r^{2^{k+1}}+2r^{2^k}+1+r^{2^{k+1}}-2r^{2^k}+1}{r^{2^{k+1}}-1}\\
&=\sqrt 2\cdot  \frac {r^{2^{k+1}}+1}{r^{2^{k+1}}-1}\\
&=X_{k+1}
\end{align}

Comment: I understood the proof, could you please elaborate on the idea on which you proceeded with? What was your thought process?

Comment: I'm working on that right now, should be an edit coming out soon.

Comment: @Santiago Added how to get to the closed form.

Comment: It makes sense, however I do not get the part where you divided by sqrt(2). The equality did not hold when I simplified it, resulting in Xk+1 = Xk+1 + 1/Xk+1

Comment: Nevermind! It is supposed to be k and not k+1 on the right side. I thought you just had rearranged an equation consisting on Xk+1 = Xk+1.

Comment: @Santiago Yep it was a typo, fixed.

Comment: The answer is great! Many thanks. Another question;
This series was defined for all rational numbers greater or equal than 1. Therefore its very first element when I plug 1 into the general sequence I posted is 3/2. Meaning X1 (or Xo in your example) is 3/2. For X2, if you plug 3/2 in my sequence, the is 17/12, but in the general form you showed, there is a slight (decimal) difference. Would you know why this happens?

Comment: @Santiago Probably just calculator rounding error. I used a CAS program, and the [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12f6x7azexov9M8AhtBw7aWFLmicJYPdl/view) is exact.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. 
Thanks a lot for your answer, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence converges, it must converge to an $x$ such that

$$x=\frac x2+\frac1x$$ or $$x^2=2.$$

Then with $x_k:=y_k+\sqrt2$,

$$y_{k+1}+\sqrt 2=\frac{y_k+\sqrt2}2+\frac1{y_k+\sqrt2}$$ and

$$y_{k+1}=\frac{y_k^2}{2(y_k+\sqrt2)}\le\frac{y_k^2}{2\sqrt2}.$$

You easily see that starting from $y_0<1$, you get a (quickly) decreasing sequence with limit $0$.

Comment: The limit is actually sqrt(2), so that cannot be correct.

Comment: @Santiago: are you serious ? Read my answer. I show twice that the answer is $\sqrt2$.

Comment: On the first part? Yes. 
Then I fail to see the the part with Yk. Could you explain?

Comment: @Santiago: it's all written. Notice that my post is three sentences long.

Comment: I understood where the limit came from, similar to a fix point as if it where a function.
What I fail to see is the use of defining Xk = Yk + sqrt(2)
Plus, the initial question is focused on a general form of the sequence for any value of k, not on its limit.

Comment: The first part is about the limit. The second is about the proof of convergence and the convergence speed. Never mind.