# Let $p ∈ N$ and let ${(a_n)}$ be the sequence defined by $a_1 =p$ and $a_{n+1} =a_n/2 +p/a_n$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $p ∈ N$ and let ${(a_n)}$ be the sequence defined by $a_1 =p$ and $a_{n+1} =a_n/2+p/a_n$ for all $n \ge 1$. Prove that ${(a_n)}$ converges and find its limit.

- I have to prove that $a_n$ is a monotone sequence first and that it is bounded then that it converges to $L$. Then I have to take the limits on both sides and end up with $L/2+p/L$ and solve for L. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried AM-GM? Also assuming it converges, what must it converges to?

Comment: @DavidCheng what does AM-GM mean?

Comment: A quick google will do it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Answer (score 1):

First prove that for large enough $n$ we have  $2\sqrt{p}\ge a_n\ge \sqrt{p}$.

Indeed if that is true for some $n$ then $a_{n+1} = a_n/2+ p/a_n \ge \sqrt{p}/2+p/(2\sqrt{p})\ge \sqrt{p}$ and $a_{n+1} \le \sqrt{p} +p/(\sqrt{p}) =2\sqrt{p}$ so we can proceed by induction. See Update below, it gives the base of induction.

Now using these inequalities it is easy to show that $a_{n+1}=a_n/2+p/a_n\ge a_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Since we have an upper bound of $2\sqrt{p}$ there is a limit.   It, as you have basically noticed,  is  $\sqrt{2p}$ (the positive solution of $L=L/2+p/L$).

So it is not true that the sequence $a_n$ is monotone. It first decreases until $a_n$ gets in the interval between $\sqrt{p}$ and $2\sqrt{p}$, and then increases.

**Update 1**.
The only non-clear part, I think, is that
$a_n$ is eventually in the interval $[\sqrt{p},2\sqrt{p}]$ so that the induction can start. This is true for $n=1$ already if $p\le 4$. So assume that $p>4$.

Suppose that $a_n\ge 2\sqrt{p}$ for some $n$. Since $a_{n+1}=a_n/2+p/a_n$ we have that $a_{n+1}\ge a_n/2\ge\sqrt{p}$ and
$a_{n+1}\le a_n/2+1/2\sqrt{p}\le a_n/2+a_n/4=(3/4)a_n$. If $a_{n+1}$ is still greater than $2\sqrt{p}$, we can continue with $a_{n+2}$ which is between $\sqrt{p}$ and $a_{n+1}(3/4)\le a_n(3/4)^2$, and so on. Since $(3/4)^k\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$ we will find $k$ such that $a_{n+k}\in [\sqrt{p},2\sqrt{p}]$, as we wanted.

**Update 2**: The condition that $p$ is an integer is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

*Since @JCAA already gave what you need, consider that this is a long comment.*

$$a_{n+1} =\frac {a_n} 2 +\frac p {a_n}$$
What I should do first  (in order to get rid rid of $p$), is to let $a_n= \sqrt 2 \sqrt p\, b_n$ to make
$$b_{n+1} =\frac 12\left({b_n} +\frac 1 {b_n}\right)$$

Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3838549/iteration-on-sequences/3838593#3838593) for a very similar problem.

Just for your curiosity,
$$a_n=\sqrt{2} \sqrt{p} \coth \left(2^{n-1} \coth
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{p}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$